# Websphere Application Login

Tags: security, authentication, websphere, jaas

I was trying to register an Application Login Module in Websphere but I don´t find any easy example in web.

There are a lot of IBM documents, but too much complex, and I can´t figure out how to register an Application Login Module.

I already have success with a System Login Module bounded to WEB_INBOUND, it works, but affects all my system. I want a Login Module to serve only my applications web, with JAAS authentication.

I´ve tried to bound a login module to existing WSLogin but it doesn´t seems to be working.

Any help ?

tks[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup security domains to get the separation you are looking for wrt to the login configurations. The security framework uses the WEB_INBOUND login configuration to authenticate the user for all web applications irrespective of adminConsole or user applications. When you create a security domain and customize the WEB_INBOUND configuration at the server/cluster domain level, it will be used for all the user web applications deployed in those processes. You need to setup the multidomain in a cell topology and assign the domain to the server/cluster where you applications are deployed.

Once you setup the domains, the WEB_INBOUND configuration at the server/cluster domain will be used by the user applications hosted in that server/cluster while the WEB_INBOUND configuration at the admin/global domain will be used for the adminConsole application at the Deploymener Management process where it is deployed.

The application JAAS login configurations are meant to be used by the applications directly. One can create an application login configuration and programmatically use it in the application to perform direct login - 
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("myAppLoginCfg1", callBackHandler);

Answer (score 1):

I asked around and this is the answer that comes from the owner of container security:

The WEB_INBOUND is a JAAS system login that is always configured by default. However, you can specify your own JAAS application login or customize the existing WEB_INBOUND system login. If you want only one application to use a different JAAS login from all your other applications, you can use a security domain that has those different security configurations. The only catch is that application server has to be in a separate server from the other apps. That way, you can map your security domain to that server.

Here's an info center article about security domains:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/tsec_sec_domains_config.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-1

And one on application logins:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/rsec_logmod.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5

And system logins:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/usec_sysjaas.html

Comment: Please read about my motivation, maybe I'm wrong, but it was what I found ...  As I read the IBM documents, they propose that System Login Modules are related to all applications, including Websphe Administrative Console, and Application Login Modules are not involved in authenticating Administrative Console. So I think that the right place to put my expecialized Login Module is as Application only. I don want my users authenticating on application context and accessing IBM Administrative Console.

Answer (score 1):

And here is a much more practical answer that comes from the security dev lead:

---

So an additional question is - why would you want to do that? Do you want to do anything specific for just one app during login that you do not want for other app logins? (I would think so) You can get the app name in your custom login module and can use that to provide your own app based login requirement in your login module (or skip it) if needed.

---

Me: Ya, this is what I would do. You can also implement this based on what is in the request. I did one where it would request a SAML token from an STS and put it on the runas subject if I could tell that the request came from WebSeal (and not if it didn't).

If what you need to do for the 'app-specific' case requires skipping what is done in ltpaLoginModule and wsMapDefaultInboundLoginModule (that should run for the other apps), you can't really do that. However, you can modify their behavior.

Read through the task I've given a link to below. Yes, I understand it is a WS-Security task, but its about using APIs. You'll get what I'm talking about if you read closely, particularly the 3rd ("When a caller...") and 5th ("To use a..") paragraphs. The parts that you should be concerned about in the code is the WSCREDENTIAL* stuff.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_config_wssec_caller_no_reg.html

Comment: As I read the IBM documents, they propose that System Login Modules are related to all applications, including Websphe Administrative Console, and Application Login Modules are not involved in authenticating Administrative Console. So I think that the right place to put my expecialized Login Module is as Application only. I don want my users authenticating on application context and accessing IBM Administrative Console.

Comment: I think that what I need is really the endpoint to where to register my Login Module, assuming that if I register on WEB_INBOUND as OPTIONAL before com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule and com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.wsMapDefaultInboundLoginModule it works fine.

Comment: My application is a full featured EJB 2.1 application, with an war component and an ejb component with MDB's and Stateless Session Beans and authentication and authorization based on JAAS. I can't secure only my web services. I really need a Login Module ;) I still will see your link carefully.